# Creating a Joomla php module

Tags: php, joomla, module, custom-component

I wish to know how to create a Joomla **PHP** Module. That is, i want to create a module where i write my own "PHP" code to perform certain functions. I thought i could just use the HTML Custom module and just write my code, but each time, i just got the same code back as plain text that has not been processed. **Even when i disable the editor from the back-end, it does the same thing.**
How can is it done? My code could perform some action similar to the following code:

```
<?php
  function moduleH()
{
  return DB::getCourses();
}
?>
```

Comment: You could start from: http://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Creating_a_simple_module

Comment: Please refer to the Joomla documentation. Everything you need for this is on there

Comment: If you just want to insert some php inside a custom html module, then these extensions might be what you want http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/core-enhancements/coding-a-scripts-integration/custom-code-in-modules.

Comment: Also this question here might be of help: http://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/655/how-do-you-make-a-new-module/661#661

Comment: Custom html is just that, it is for custom html, though you can also run a content plugin. Clone one of the simple modules that kind of does what you want (display a list, submit a form etc) that is there, change all the names in the xml and the top level file, add a helper if you need it (probably that will have your php) and then make a simple layout which you can probably do by editing the existing one you cloned. It looks like you want a list, so copy latest articles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't even need to create a module. JCE Editor allows you to do that (provided you allow PHP in the default options for JCE). Or you can just use Jumi which is a Joomla extension specifically built for this purpose.

Comment: If you can code at all a real module is 3 files and takes about 5 minutes to make if you already have the code in hand and then won't have the performance and sanity hit of doing the php in the middle of a layout.  And then you will be able to reuse it anywhere including in  the middle of an article and you'll have the advantage of an overridable layout with a UI for configuring options if you want.